# Real time chart using jquery Flot that shows time accurately?

Tags: jquery, flot

I am trying to use Flot: http://www.flotcharts.org to create a realtime chart that is updated via ajax. I am basing my code on the following:

```
var cpu = [], cpuCore = [], disk = [];
var dataset;
var totalPoints = 100;
var updateInterval = 5000;
var now = new Date().getTime();

var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            lineWidth: 1.2
        },
        bars: {
            align: "center",
            fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1}] },
            barWidth: 500,
            lineWidth: 1
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [60, "second"],
        tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
            var date = new Date(v);

            if (date.getSeconds() % 20 == 0) {
                var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

                return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        },
        axisLabel: "Time",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 10
    },
    yaxes: [
        {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            tickSize: 5,
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                if (v % 10 == 0) {
                    return v + "%";
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            axisLabel: "CPU loading",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 6
        }, {
            max: 5120,
            position: "right",
            axisLabel: "Disk",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 6
        }
    ],
    legend: {
        noColumns: 0,
        position:"nw"
    },
    grid: {      
        backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
    }
};

function initData() {
    for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++) {
        var temp = [now += updateInterval, 0];

        cpu.push(temp);
        cpuCore.push(temp);
        disk.push(temp);
    }
}

function GetData() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/AjaxUpdateChart.aspx",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: update,
        error: function () {
            setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
        }
    });
}

var temp;

function update(_data) {
    cpu.shift();
    cpuCore.shift();
    disk.shift();

    now += updateInterval

    temp = [now, _data.cpu];
    cpu.push(temp);

    temp = [now, _data.core];
    cpuCore.push(temp);

    temp = [now, _data.disk];
    disk.push(temp);

    dataset = [
        { label: "CPU:" + _data.cpu + "%", data: cpu, lines: { fill: true, lineWidth: 1.2 }, color: "#00FF00" },
        { label: "Disk:" + _data.disk + "KB", data: disk, color: "#0044FF", bars: { show: true }, yaxis: 2 },
        { label: "CPU Core:" + _data.core + "%", data: cpuCore, lines: { lineWidth: 1.2}, color: "#FF0000" }        
    ];

    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);
    setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    initData();

    dataset = [        
        { label: "CPU", data: cpu, lines:{fill:true, lineWidth:1.2}, color: "#00FF00" },
        { label: "Disk:", data: disk, color: "#0044FF", bars: { show: true }, yaxis: 2 },
        { label: "CPU Core", data: cpuCore, lines: { lineWidth: 1.2}, color: "#FF0000" }
    ];

    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);
    setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
});
```

A working example can be seen here: http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/tester-11.html

But why is the time axis along the bottom back to front?

And I have also noticed that it does not keep time accurately and it gets further out of sync the longer its left running. Can this be overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `now -= totalPoints * updateInterval;` at the beginning of the `initData()` function so that the current time is at the right end of the x-axis instead of the left end.

And change `now += updateInterval` to `now = new Date().getTime();` in the `update(_data)` function so that new data points always have the current time.

---

I would also recommend to change the `tickFormatter` function to

```
    tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
        var date = new Date(v);
        if (date.getSeconds() == 0) {
            var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
            return hours + ":" + minutes;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    },
```

and directly call `GetData();` at the end of the `document.ready()` function (instead of the `setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);`).

Comment: Thanks, these modification do appear to working. I am not sure I understand how the first part puts the current at the right end of the x-axis?

Comment: The loop inserts 100 (= `totalPoints`) data points into an array. If we start with `now` it is the first (left) data point. If we subtract (100 * `updateInterval`) and add one `updateInterval` in each step, at the end of the loop (the last / right data point) we are back at `now`.

Comment: Makes sense (sort of). Do you think there is any way to smooth out the chart? I realise its being redrawn on every update. Iv tried altering the totalpoints and update interval. it works to a certain extent but ends up with much larger grid spaces. Also I accept that the speed at which the ajax requests come back will have an effect.

Comment: You could smooth it out if you control the server and provide regular data with included timestamp so that you always use the time the data was measured instead of the time it arrives at the client (which varies depending on the ajax request as you already said).

Comment: Ok I will try to implement that. If i alter var totalPoints = 500;
var updateInterval = 50; And change  tickSize: [10, "second"]  The chart starts off with wide grid lines then they gradually get smaller as the data comes in. Any idea whats going on there?

Comment: With regards to smoothing it out do you mean I should provoide an array of data ahead of time on the chart as in to give it a head start then just keep updating to keep it smooth?